# How to assign a variable to a "formatter" function?

Tags: python, string

In python, I can create the following function:

```
In [1]: num_formatter = '{:.4g}'.format
In [2]: num_formatter(1.234567)
Out[2]: '1.235'
```

But what I want now is something like:

```
In [1]: num_fig = 4
In [2]: num_formatter = '{:.{nf}g}'.format(nf=num_fig)
In [3]: num_formatter(1.234567)
Out[3]: '1.235'
```

However, this code gives me error of 'Replacement index 0 out of range for positional args tuple'. Which I understand, it's asking what to do with the input 1.234567, but I don't know how to fix it. I tried using *args or **kargs inside the format, but that does not work. How would this be done?

Comment: Turn it into a function or a lambda?

Comment: Or use a `functools.partial`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `f` string

**Ex:**

```
nf = 4
num_formatter = f'{{:.{nf}g}}'.format
print(num_formatter(1.234567)) # --> 1.235
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a lambda:

```py
>>> num_formatter = lambda n,p: f'{n:.{p}g}'
>>> num_formatter(1.234567,4)
'1.235'
```

Another option, is to create a configurable class which is a better option than global variables:

```py
>>> class Formatter:
...     def __init__(self,precision=None):
...         self.set_precision(2 if precision is None else precision)
...     def __call__(self,n):
...         return f'{n:.{self.p}g}'
...     def set_precision(self,p):
...         self.p = p
...         
>>> num_formatter = Formatter()
>>> num_formatter(1.23456)
'1.2'
>>> num_formatter.set_precision(4)
>>> num_formatter(1.23456)
'1.235'
>>> num_formatter = Formatter(3)
>>> num_formatter(1.23456)
'1.23'
```